# Array initialization in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization

I'm new to C++, and I want to know if this valid.

So I want to create an array of strings, but I wont know the size of the array I need until a value is passed in to a function within the class I'm working in. So, can I do this:

```
string sList[];

void init(unsigned int size=1)
{
    sList = new string[size];

 }
```

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm a Java guy new to C++.

EDIT: This is an assignment that involves me writing an array wrapper class. If I could use vector<>, trust me, I would.

Comment: This is valid, but do you have a reason not to use `std::vector<>` instead of flat arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I have to write a wrapper class for arrays, and the function above is basically the constructor.

Comment: @user1795374: No, you definitely do not have to write a wrapper class yourself in C++. Whoever is telling you this is either lying to you or wants to make you unemployable in the C++ job market.

Comment: When I said I have to, I mean it's an assignment.

Comment: Why would a constructor be called `init`? There's absolutely positively no reason for that being an assignment requirement, and that will quickly make you unemployable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, although `string sList[]` should be `string *sList`. Don't forget the `delete [] sList` at the end.

As many others say, you can use `std::vector` if you want, but getting some practice with arrays is an excellent way to learn how the memory management works and I encourage you to explore it further.

Comment: Or use `unique_ptr< string[] >` and forget about `delete[]`. Though I also like `vector` better.

Comment: well, as I was saying, it is better to start old school until you get a good understanding of how it works, so I would advice to stay away from smart pointers as well, at least until you know how to code one yourself.

Comment: “it is better to start old school” – no, that is a myth. It’s wrong. [Education works better when you start top-down rather than working bottom up.](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1avhr4/introduction_to_c_and_c_electrical_engineering/c98i7jo)

Comment: Well, i am not qualified and motivated enough to sparkle a debate on education now. My point was just, I see a lot of students sorting arrays using `object.sort()` because it is there, without even wondering what are the different ways to sort an array and which one would you choose in which situation. I think telling the OP pointers are outdated and he shouldn't use them when he is showing interest is bad advice, feel free to disagree.

Comment: @EdS. OP: "but I wont know the size of the array I need until a value is passed in to a function" = the size of the array is only known at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

A *new-expression* (such as `new string[size]`) returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated object. In this case, it returns a pointer to the first `string` object in the dynamically allocated array. So to make this work, `sList` should be a pointer:

```
string* sList;
```

It is important to remember that you must always `delete`/`delete[]` and object that has been created with `new`/`new[]`. So you must at some point `delete[] sList`. If you don't do this, the memory allocated for the array of `string`s will “never” be deallocated.

However, you'll be in a much better situation if you use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead, rather than doing your own dynamic allocation.

Comment: Could I do this in my destructor for the class that this is inside of?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> sList;

void init(unsigned int size = 1)
{
    sList.resize(size);
}

int main()
{
    init(25);
}
```